# Lock-free implementation of getAndUpdate() using atomic CAS (Compare-And-Swap) operation

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, kotlin, lock-free, atomic

We have the following class written in Kotlin Native with the new Memory Manager (which doesn't require to freeze objects):

```kotlin
import kotlin.native.concurrent.AtomicReference

class AtomicRef<V>(initialValue: V) {

    private val atom = AtomicReference(initialValue)

    /**
     * Get the current value
     */
    fun get(): V = atom.get()

    /**
     * Atomically compare the current value with `expected`, 
     * and set it to `new` if the current and the expected values are the same.
     *
     * @return `true` if successful, `false` return indicates that
     *   the actual value was not equal to the expected value.
     */
    fun compareAndSet(expected: V, new: V): Boolean = 
        atom.compareAndSet(expected, new)

    /**
     * Atomically compare the current value with `expected`, 
     * and set it to `new` if the current and the expected values are the same.
     *
     * @return the witness value, 
     *   which will be the same as the `expected` value if successful.
     */
    fun compareAndExchange(expected: V, new: V): V =
        atom.compareAndSwap(expected, new)

    /**
     * Atomically updates the current value with the results 
     * of applying the given function, returning the previous value.
     *
     * @param updateFunction a side-effect-free function
     * @return the previous value
     */
    fun getAndUpdate(updateFunction: (V) -> V): V {
        while(true) {
            val prev = get()
            val next = updateFunction(prev)
            if (compareAndSet(prev, next)) return prev
        }
    }
}
```

`compareAndSet` and `compareAndExchange` implementations delegate to the corresponding Kotlin stdlib `AtomicReference` methods ([`compareAndSet`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.native.concurrent/-atomic-reference/compare-and-set.html) and [`compareAndSwap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.native.concurrent/-atomic-reference/compare-and-swap.html), respectively), which provide native bug- and livelock-free implementations.

`getAndUpdate` implementation is well known, and can be found, for example, in the Java [`j.u.c.AtomicReference`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk8-b120/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.java#L146) class, or in the [`atomicfu`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-atomicfu/blob/0.20.0/atomicfu/src/commonMain/kotlin/kotlinx/atomicfu/AtomicFU.common.kt#L172) library by JetBrains.

I'd like to rewrite the implementation of the `getAndUpdate()` function to use `compareAndExchange` and avoid calling `get()` on every loop iteration.

I've come up with the following implementation:

```kotlin
    fun getAndUpdate(updateFunction: (V) -> V): V {
        var prev = get()
        while(true) {
            val expected = prev
            val next = updateFunction(expected)
            prev = compareAndExchange(expected, next)
            if (prev == expected) return prev
        }
    }
```

Is it correct, and will it work the same way as the one using `compareAndSet`?

**UPDATE**

I've found a [ticket with a discussion](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8141640) in the OpenJDK tracker, where one of the OpenJDK members suggests a similar Java implementation for `AtomicInteger.getAndUpdate`:

> ```java
> public final int getAndUpdate(IntUnaryOperator updateFunction) {
>     for (int prev = get() ;;) {
>         int next = updateFunction.applyAsInt(prev);
>         if (prev == (prev = compareAndExchange(prev, next)))
>             return prev;
>     } 
> }
> ```
>
> This seems optimal when `compareAndExchange` gets compiled to a native instruction. If it does not, and the hardware has spurious failures, `compareAndExchange` gets compiled to a loop, but there's no wasted extra volatile read on failure because the value read is returned to our loop.
>
> If this is not a good use case for `compareAndExchange`, then what is? It's currently unused.

The Java code above can be expressed in Kotlin as:

```kotlin
fun getAndUpdate(updateFunction: (V) -> V): V {
    var prev = get()
    while (true) {
        val next = updateFunction(prev)
        val witnessed = compareAndExchange(prev, next)
        if (prev == witnessed) return prev
        prev = witnessed
    }
}
```

which is quite close to the code I planned to use for `getAndUpdate`.

Comment: I worry about [livelock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Livelock). It's not obvious to me that either one of those `while` loops will provably terminate. Wouldn't you like to `sleep()` or even busy-wait some tiny random amount? Then [w.h.p.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/With_high_probability) someone will win while other thread(s) are sleeping. (cf the exponential backoff argument in Ethernet V2 [Blue Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet#Standardization).)

Comment: @J_H If I'm not mistaken, the existing `getAndUpdate` implementation (using `compareAndSet`) as provided is exactly like how Kotlin has implemented `MutableStateFlow`. And no, you do not want to sleep or busy-wait.

Comment: Ok, I'm sure you're right. Typically I would look for some model checking results to prove a distributed algorithm is free of pathological cases. Here, I suspect [Spin](https://spinroot.com/spin/whatispin.html) wouldn't give a thumbs up, but would instead offer a counter-example where two threads race each other producing livelock. I guess it's the difference between theory (balance it on a knife's edge) and practice (eventually something disturbs it). In practice I _have_ seen a hundred IMAP clients synchronize with one another based on when server is busy, trashing production service. :-(

Comment: @SimonForsberg yes, it's also exactly as `AtomicRef.getAndUpdate` from the JetBrains atomicfu library is implemented: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-atomicfu/blob/master/atomicfu/src/commonMain/kotlin/kotlinx/atomicfu/AtomicFU.common.kt#L171

Comment: @J_H for the simplicity let's assume there won't be livelock for multiple threads calling `getAndUpdate`, since if the read value has changed between `get` and `compareAndSet`, then it means the `compareAndSet` has succeeded for one of the other threads (we're assuming that `compareAndSet` provides `forward progress guarantee`).

Comment: @J_H a CAS-loop doesn't livelock because the shared state is only updated when the CAS succeeds. Spinning threads aren't changing the state, so they cannot make each other spin more. Spinning threads do make each other slower though, by all fighting over exclusive access to the cache line that contains the state.

Comment: @harold It can livelock if the CAS itself is implemented incorrectly, for example, if it's implemented using LL/SC instructions (which are prone to livelock on some architectures) and **without** additional measures in the implementation to avoid the livelock. These are architecture specific details, and we just make a fair assumption that the CAS implementation provided by the Kotlin `stdlib` is bug- and livelock-free. (In case somebody is interested in the reasons of LL/SC livelock, here is a nice summary: https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2016-May/099490.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite the `getAndUpdate()` function using the `compareAndExchange()` method as follows:

```
fun getAndUpdate(updateFunction: (V) -> V): V {
    var prev: V
    var next: V
    do {
       prev = compareAndExchange(null as V, null as V)
       next = updateFunction(prev)
    } while (!compareAndSet(prev, next))
    return prev
}
```

Here, the `getAndUpdate()` function now utilizes the `compareAndExchange()` method. It will attempt to perform the update in a loop until the `compareAndSet()` method returns true, which means the update was successful. The `compareAndExchange()` method is called with null values to obtain the current value without modifying it, which effectively replaces the `get()` call